# Hiding label in Windows Form takes 244 ms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to see if I can find the source of a problem. I am trying to use .NET 4.0 on a slim/compact computer. When running the app with adding a `StopWatch` it takes **244 ms** to run just a simple line of `label.visible = false;` where on my computer it only takes **22 ms**. Other parts of the code are running 100% fine, it's just this area. What could be causing this?

Here is the system that I am trying to run the application on. I know its a cheap computer, but this is the **only** application that will be running on it. I have went through and uninstalled all default programs that were installed by Acer and ran all the Windows Updates.

[Amazon.com - Acer Aspire Revo AR3700-U3002 Slim and Compact Desktop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00433SP6G)

Product Features

- 1.8 GHz Intel Atom D525 dual-core processor
- 2 GB of installed DDR3 RAM
- 250 GB SATA hard drive (5400 RPM)
- Integrated nVIDIA Ion Graphics
- Windows 7 Home Premium

Processor, Memory, and Motherboard

- Hardware Platform: Unknown
- Processor: 1.8 GHz Intel Atom
- Number of Processors: 1
- RAM: 2 GB
- RAM Type: Unknown
- Memory Slots: 2

Hard Drive

- Size: 250 GB
- Type: Unknown
- Speed: 5400 rpm

Comment: So is it 244 milliseconds as per the title or 244 seconds as per the body?

Comment: also: show the code in question in context

Comment: How (on earth) do you profile that the line takes 244msecs? My guess it just gets executed a million times :)

Comment: Also `Windows 7 Home Premium` on an Atom? Don't do that! You know that most of **[Winforms is supported on Mono/Linux too...](http://mono-framework.com/MoMA)**

Comment: Do other parts of the system take 10 times longer on the smaller system than on your larger system?

Comment: Sorry it is in MILLASECONDS not seconds. Below is a link to the code along with the debug information. Everything else appears to be quick, except this part which you can just see the difference when using the app. http://www.stubwire.com/_test/sample_label_takes_long_time.txt

Comment: One of the problems is that you're concatenating strings (at least, I think `Config.Application.debugLoggs` is a string), which is going to affect your timings quite a bit. Do you call this just one time? If so, then JIT time is going to be a factor. Does it take 244 ms if you call it again, right after you call it the first time? Also, if you're timing this in debug mode, or with the debugger attached, your timings are going to be completely unreliable.

Comment: The only reason I added the Config.Application.debugLogs is to figure out why the screen was lagging. Because I don't have anything else installed on this box, I installed it on the target machine and then had it just output the data. I won't have access to this machine until tonight, I am just trying to figure out what I can do to fix it. I will have to test if I call the same label visiable twice if it takes awhile, but if you look at the above link it lists out timing after a couple labels and each of them does take awhile.

Comment: Try running the same application in release mode and build the debug output using the StringBuilder class.  Also just for this test try to reduce the logging overhead and see if you get a faster reponse.

Comment: Another thought, also check for a graphics driver updates from the manufacture's website.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it could depend on what platform you're developing on too. GDI+ acceleration was removed in Windows 7/Vista. Thus, making all GDI+ operations, even simple ones such as hiding/showing of forms, much slower.

This is one thing that was not removed in Windows Server 2008, but has since been removed in Windows Server 2008 R2. So if you're using Windows XP or below, or Windows Server 2008 or below for your development machine, it could be notably faster, than a similar Windows 7 or Windows Vista machine.

Regardless of the hardware acceleration, a comparison of video cards could be in order too. Built-in video cards on low-end machines, rarely compare to the ones included in development machines.

Other performance problems is the very real lack of RAM (especially if it's running 64-bit), it could be pushing the GDI calls out to the incredibly slow hard drive (5400 rpm) if it doesn't have enough RAM.

Try implementing the same test in WPF? If the speeds are very similar in WPF, it's probably due to a video/hardware acceleration problem, or a memory problem, as WPF benefits from full 3D hardware acceleration, and uses your video memory primarily for the UI instead of your system RAM.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. I have not tested with WPF as the entire program is written in Windows Forms and don't really want to rewrite it. I have tried to bump the ram from 2gb to 4gb just to see the difference, but having a hard time finding the ram. This is using Win7 Home Prem 64bit. This computer was only $200 as I was trying to go the cheapest route possible for running this software but sounds like I need to get better hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Run the example multiple times and get some more information. Especially call the StopWatch multiple times in a row to check what resolution it supports.

Jit compiling can be really slow on a slow machine too so run it multiple times or NGEN the code.

Check if the hardware is running on full performance and not on 'minimal cpu speed' etc. A laptop moved to power saving mode can be really slow.

By implementing custom drawing you can see if the draw action or the 'Event' action is taking all the time.

Also check if you have many running applications, some laptops have a heap of software pre-installed slowing down the machine to a crawl.

In short give us much more information. Debug what part of the operation is slow and then get back to us.