# c# black (not rendered) components when showing form

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, components

I have my application in tray icon and if I call Show(); the Form blink -> some components are not rendered for a few ms. It blinks and then it's ok, why is this doing?
[image: imagine problem]

Comment: Try calling `Form.Invalidate()` after `Show`.

Comment: BTW are those custom controls?

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF?

Comment: If they are custom controls, in `OnPaint` call `Graphics.Clear(Color.White)` before painting anything else. I think Aero might enable doublebuffering and then `OnBackgroundPaint` is not called (IIRC).

Comment: winforms, .NET components (not custom)

Comment: @sczdavos: What controls are those specifically? IOW the type/class name.

Comment: @leppie dateTimePicker, numericUpDown, button, checkbox, but I don't think so this is the source of problem

Comment: Can there be so much components -> slow rendering?
Can I speed up it? Or it's normal?

Comment: Do you have something going on in a timer that is hogging the CPU?

Comment: Not exactly, I have timer for showing actual time, but it's only once per sec refreshing actual time. It's nothing hogging the CPU I think.

Comment: @sczdavos: Those black controls look nothing like any of the controls that you mention. With Aero off , they look like white labels to me.

Comment: This is what I mean -> http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/clockworkdrawing.png/

Comment: Have you got an OnLoad event on the form and what does the code look like?  What spec machine are you using?  What version of Windows is it (i.e. Vista/Win7)?  Are all updates installed?

Comment: Looks like it is not running in a message loop.

Comment: @James Yes I have, but it do the same if I hide form and show it again (it's not calling Load event). I'm running x86 Windows 7 with all updates.

Comment: @leppie What does message loop exactly means? I've never heard this.

Comment: I'm interested in the platform being used because there was another article about slow label behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213682/hiding-label-in-windows-form-takes-244-ms, so I was wondering if there is a connection, maybe the way .NET draws labels or something?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am going to experiment with uninstalling versions of .net